# How to show two buttons for two cases in ListView?

Tags: android

I have two button and i would like to show one button ''NEW TV SHOW'' if year of tv show is above 2014 and i have successed in that applying this condition:

```
if (serija.getYear() >= 2014) {
    prikaziDugme();
} else {
    nePrikazujDugme();
}
```

but when applying this second condition for other button it's not working:

```
if (serija.getPremijera() == "premijera"){
        prikaziPremijeraDugme();
        nePrikazujDugme();
        nePrikazujZvezdu();
    } else{
       nePrikazujDugme();
       nePrikazujPremijeraDugme();
    }
```

This second condition say that this button will show only if there is String `"premijera"`, but i don't want then to show this first button there and also i wouldn't want to show one ImageView there which is representing rating star. I have set the visibility to this second button in layout `gone` and in my method i'm setting the visibility to "visible" and calling that method in this if statement. But something isn't working.

Here is my whole code of adapter where i'm trying to finish this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_show_now_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.year);
        TextView kanal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kanal);
        TextView showtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vreme_prikazivanja_serije);
        TextView premijera = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.premijera);
        btn_novo = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_premijera = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        rating_star = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating_star);

        // getting tvShow data for the row
        Serija serija = tvShowItems.get(position);

        // setting the result for images and textviews
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(serija.getImage(), imageLoader);
        title.setText(serija.getTitle());
        rating.setText(serija.getRating());
        year.setText(String.valueOf(serija.getYear()));
        kanal.setText(serija.getKanal());
        showtime.setText(serija.getShowtime());
        premijera.setText(serija.getPremijera());



        if (serija.getYear() >= 2014) {
           prikaziDugme();
        } else {
           nePrikazujDugme();
        }

        if (serija.getPremijera() == "premijera"){
            prikaziPremijeraDugme();
            nePrikazujDugme();
            nePrikazujZvezdu();
        } else{
           nePrikazujDugme();
           nePrikazujPremijeraDugme();
        } 

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        return convertView;
    }

    private void prikaziDugme() {
        btn_novo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void nePrikazujDugme() {
        btn_novo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void prikaziPremijeraDugme() {
        btn_premijera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void nePrikazujPremijeraDugme() {
        btn_premijera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void nePrikazujZvezdu() {
        rating_star.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

I have tried also with cases, but didn't have luck with it.

Comment: which thing is not working, something????????

Comment: I mean only first statement is showing. I'm getting only first button, but second button isn't showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
if (serija.getPremijera() == "premijera"){
...
..
}
```

Use this:

```
if (serija.getPremijera().equals("premijera")){
...
..
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, but now the first button isn't showing. Should i put this method for not showing second button in to the first statement?

Comment: yes put the button you want to show according to the condition.